# Find the destination owner (schema) for replication on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

We have a table replicating to another server with a different Schema at the destination.  When I set the replication up it shows as destination owner in the GUI.  I am trying to create some reports and need to look at the publication and look for what the destination schema would be.

Unfortunately when I query the table [distribution].[dbo].[MSarticles] the destination owner column is null.  Is there somewhere else I can find this info?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the [publicationDatabase].[dbo].[sysarticles].dest_owner column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `[distribution].[dbo].[MSarticles]` use `[publicationDatabase].[dbo].[sysarticles]`. Use dest_owner column.

Detail here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/sysarticles-transact-sql